# R: Fill in all elements of sequence of datetime with patchy periodic datetime information

Tags: r, datetime, sequence

I guess I don't even know really what to 'title' this question as.
But I think this is quite a common data manipulation requirement.

I have data that has a periodic exchange between two parties of a quantity of a good. The exchanges are made hourly. Here is an example data frame:

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(Seller = as.character(c("A","A","A","A","A","A")), 
                       Buyer = c("B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                       DateTimeFrom = c("1/07/2013 0:00","1/07/2013 9:00","1/07/2013 0:00","1/07/2013 6:00","1/07/2013 8:00","2/07/2013 9:00"),
                       DateTimeTo = c("1/07/2013 8:00","1/07/2013 15:00","2/07/2013 8:00","1/07/2013 9:00","1/07/2013 12:00","2/07/2013 16:00"),
                       Qty = c(50,10,20,25,5,5)
                       )

df$DateTimeFrom <- as.POSIXct(df$DateTimeFrom, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', tz = 'GMT')
df$DateTimeTo <- as.POSIXct(df$DateTimeTo, format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', tz = 'GMT')

> df
  Seller Buyer        DateTimeFrom          DateTimeTo Qty
1      A     B 2013-07-01 00:00:00 2013-07-01 08:00:00  50
2      A     B 2013-07-01 09:00:00 2013-07-01 15:00:00  10
3      A     B 2013-07-01 00:00:00 2013-07-02 08:00:00  20
4      A     C 2013-07-01 06:00:00 2013-07-01 09:00:00  25
5      A     C 2013-07-01 08:00:00 2013-07-01 12:00:00   5
6      A     C 2013-07-02 09:00:00 2013-07-02 16:00:00   5
```

So, for example, the first row of this data frame says that the Seller "A" sells 50 units of the good to the buyer "B" every hour from midnight on 1/7/13 until 8am on 1/7/13. You can also notice that some of these exchanges between the same two parties can overlap, but just with a different negotiated quantity.

What I need to do (and need your help with) is to generate a sequence covering all hours over this two day period that sums the total quantity exchanged in that hour between two sellers over all neogociations.
Here would be the resulting dataframe.

```
DateTimeSeq <- data.frame(seq(ISOdate(2013,7,1,0),by = "hour", length.out = 48))
colnames(DateTimeSeq) <- c("DateTime")

#What the Answer should be
DateTimeSeq$QtyAB <- c(70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
DateTimeSeq$QtyAC <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,25,25,30,30,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

> DateTimeSeq
              DateTime QtyAB QtyAC
1  2013-07-01 00:00:00    70     0
2  2013-07-01 01:00:00    70     0
3  2013-07-01 02:00:00    70     0
4  2013-07-01 03:00:00    70     0
5  2013-07-01 04:00:00    70     0
6  2013-07-01 05:00:00    70     0
7  2013-07-01 06:00:00    70    25
8  2013-07-01 07:00:00    70    25
9  2013-07-01 08:00:00    70    30
10 2013-07-01 09:00:00    30    30
11 2013-07-01 10:00:00    30     5
12 2013-07-01 11:00:00    30     5
13 2013-07-01 12:00:00    30     5
14 2013-07-01 13:00:00    30     0
15 2013-07-01 14:00:00    30     0
.... etc
```

Anybody able to lend a hand?

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution which uses the `dplyr` and `reshape` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape)
```

Firstly, we should expand the dataframe so that everything is in an hourly format. This can be done using the `do` part of `dplyr`.

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  do(data.frame(Seller=.$Seller, 
                Buyer=.$Buyer,
                Qty=.$Qty,
                DateTimeCurr=seq(from=.$DateTimeFrom, to=.$DateTimeTo, by="hour")))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [66 x 4]
Groups: <by row>

   Seller Buyer Qty        DateTimeCurr
1       A     B  50 2013-07-01 00:00:00
2       A     B  50 2013-07-01 01:00:00
3       A     B  50 2013-07-01 02:00:00
...
```

From there it is trivial to get the correct id's and summarise the total using the `group_by` function.

```
df1 <- df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  do(data.frame(Seller=.$Seller, 
                Buyer=.$Buyer,
                Qty=.$Qty,
                DateTimeCurr=seq(from=.$DateTimeFrom, to=.$DateTimeTo, by="hour"))) %>%
  group_by(Seller, Buyer, DateTimeCurr) %>%
  summarise(TotalQty=sum(Qty)) %>% 
  mutate(id=paste0("Qty", Seller, Buyer))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [48 x 5]
Groups: Seller, Buyer

   Seller Buyer        DateTimeCurr TotalQty    id
1       A     B 2013-07-01 00:00:00       70 QtyAB
2       A     B 2013-07-01 01:00:00       70 QtyAB
3       A     B 2013-07-01 02:00:00       70 QtyAB
```

From this dataframe, all we have to do is cast it into the format you have above.

```
> cast(df1,  DateTimeCurr~ id, value="TotalQty")
          DateTimeCurr QtyAB QtyAC
1  2013-07-01 00:00:00    70    NA
2  2013-07-01 01:00:00    70    NA
3  2013-07-01 02:00:00    70    NA
4  2013-07-01 03:00:00    70    NA
5  2013-07-01 04:00:00    70    NA
6  2013-07-01 05:00:00    70    NA
```

---

So the whole piece of code

```
df1 <- df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  do(data.frame(Seller=.$Seller, 
                Buyer=.$Buyer,
                Qty=.$Qty,
                DateTimeCurr=seq(from=.$DateTimeFrom, to=.$DateTimeTo, by="hour"))) %>%
  group_by(Seller, Buyer, DateTimeCurr) %>%
  summarise(TotalQty=sum(Qty)) %>% 
  mutate(id=paste0("Qty", Seller, Buyer))

cast(df1,  DateTimeCurr~ id, value="TotalQty")
```

Comment: Ahh yes. It was the do argument from dplyr I was after.
The final result using your code is almost there. I just merged it back onto the DateTimeSeq df in order to obtain the full 48 hours over the two days.
df1 <- merge(DateTimeSeq, df1, all.x=TRUE, by = c('DateTime'))

Because I was after the full 24 periods, even if  both AB and AC were NA.

Also to finish it off I put zero quantities where NA was formed.
df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0

Thanks!